# View width problem when going landscape

Tags: android, view, width, landscape

I have a TabHost->LinearLayout->Framelayout (all with the attribute android:layout_width="fill_parent")

In turn, the view contained in the FrameLayout is such that: ScrollView->HorizontalScrollView->TableLayout ,again all of them with the attribute android:layout_width="fill_parent".

So why when I go landscape the view uses about 60% of the screen's width ?

Maybe such hierarchy of objects is not recommended ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I do not know what is going on, but `fill_parent` is [deprecated](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html#FILL_PARENT) - use `match_parent` instead. But this should not cause your problem.

Comment: I'm stuck with 4 which doesn't recognize the match_parent attr, so can't even try it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this order,first horizontal scroll View

```
 HorizontalScrollView->ScrollView->TableLayout
```